# how to merge few flowfile into one

Tags: merge, apache-nifi, flowfile

I need one flowfile on end of queue

[image]

my config now,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Minimum number of entries set to one simply mean if number of incoming entries met one then merge the flowfile together.
For Example if you set to 2 (regardless of the rest of the settings) this processor merge to flowfile together. So if you have 4 incoming flowfile you will have 2 flowfile after merge.